# Excel code or VBA to Achieve Lookup across rows and columns

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

[image: Target table]

Above is the table i am looking to populate, Column A contains some Abbreviations and Column B is where result would be returned, this is available in the `Tool` sheet

[image: table containing lookup value]

Available in `Tool Backsheet` sheet This table above is whew the information to be returned is, so for every item in column A of "Tool" sheet, search for it in column B:F of `Tool Backsheet` sheet and if match is found, return the value in column A to the column B of `Tool` sheet.

I am not sure if VBA seem like a complicated approach or just formula would suffice

[image: Expected Result]

Above is what i am expecting, in the case of multiple abbreviations present in multiple rows of the `Tool Backsheet`, return them all separating by comma.

I wrote a bit of VBA, but doesnt seem to work

```
Sub LookupAndIndexMatch()
    Dim wsTool As Worksheet
    Dim wsToolBacksheet As Worksheet
    Dim lastRowTool As Long
    Dim lastRowToolBacksheet As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim lookupValue As String
    
    Set wsTool = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tool")
    Set wsToolBacksheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tool Backsheet")
    
    lastRowTool = wsTool.Cells(wsTool.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lastRowToolBacksheet = wsToolBacksheet.Cells(wsToolBacksheet.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    
    For i = 2 To lastRowTool
        lookupValue = wsTool.Cells(i, "A").Value
        For j = 1 To 5
            If wsToolBacksheet.Cells(1, j + 1).Value = lookupValue Then
                wsTool.Cells(i, "B").Value = wsToolBacksheet.Cells(j + 1, 1).Value
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

If formula could work, i am open to it as well.
Thank you

Comment: Result for "SS" looks wrong?  FYI "doesnt seem to work" doesn't tell us much - what does your code do *instead* of working?

Comment: Should be doable with formulas FILTER and TRANSPOSE I think.

Comment: IN expected row SS isn't it `Communications` instead `Commitment`?

Comment: Yes, that was an error from my end, coz i had to manually type the result i was looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Dictionary object is used to get unique list and `Objectives`
- Load data into array to improve efficiency

```
Option Explicit

Sub LookupAndIndexMatch()
    Dim wsTool As Worksheet
    Dim wsToolBacksheet As Worksheet
    Dim lastRowTool As Long
    Dim lastRowToolBacksheet As Long, lastCol As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim lookupValue As String
    Dim objDic As Object
    Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set wsTool = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tool")
    ' Get sheet object
    Set wsToolBacksheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tool Backsheet")
    ' Get table size
    lastRowTool = wsTool.Cells(wsTool.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lastRowToolBacksheet = wsToolBacksheet.Cells(wsToolBacksheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lastCol = wsToolBacksheet.Cells(1, wsToolBacksheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Dim arrData, rngData As Range, sKey
    ' Load data from wsToolBacksheet
    Set rngData = wsToolBacksheet.Range("A2", wsToolBacksheet.Cells(lastRowToolBacksheet, lastCol))
    arrData = rngData.Value
    ' Get unique list w/ Dict object
    For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
        For j = LBound(arrData, 2) + 1 To UBound(arrData, 2)
            sKey = Trim(arrData(i, j))
            If Len(sKey) > 0 Then
                If objDic.exists(sKey) Then
                    objDic(sKey) = objDic(sKey) & "," & arrData(i, 1)
                Else
                    objDic(sKey) = arrData(i, 1)
                End If
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    ' Populate wsTool
    Set rngData = wsTool.Range("A2:B" & lastRowTool)
    arrData = rngData.Value
    For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
        sKey = Trim(arrData(i, 1))
        If objDic.exists(sKey) Then arrData(i, 2) = objDic(sKey)
    Next i
    rngData.Value = arrData
End Sub
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Dictionary object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```vb
Sub LookupAndIndexMatch()
    
    Dim wsTool As Worksheet, wsToolBacksheet As Worksheet, c As Range
    Dim lastRowTB As Long, rngMatch As Range, v, m
    
    Set wsTool = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tool")
    Set rngMatch = wsTool.Range("A2:A" & wsTool.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
   
    Set wsToolBacksheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tool Backsheet")
    lastRowTB = wsToolBacksheet.Cells(wsToolBacksheet.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    
    'Loop any cells with values
    For Each c In wsToolBacksheet.Range("B2:F" & lastRowTB). _
                                  SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Cells
         
         m = Application.Match(c.Value, rngMatch, 0)
         If Not IsError(m) Then 'got a match in Col A on Tool?
            With rngMatch.Cells(m).Offset(0, 1) 'Col B
                v = .Value
                'add/append value to any existing value
                v = v & IIf(Len(v) > 0, ",", "") & c.EntireRow.Columns("A").Value
                .Value = v
            End With
         End If
    Next c
  
End Sub
```